# Can't Connect Facebook App to Facebook Page

Tags: android, ios, facebook, share

**Goal:** When sharing to Facebook from within iOS and Android we need the "via AppName" link when clicked from a computer browser to direct users to a Facebook page for the organization.

**Info:** With other apps we use, this has been successful when 1) the facebook developer account that created the Facebook App is an admin on the Organization's Facebook Page, and 2) the app display name exactly matches the Organization's Facebook page name. As long as both of these things are true, in the app's App Details section, under "Contact Info" and "App Page", there is a dropdown where pages we admin are available to link.

**Issue:** The Organization's name that we are an admin for has a page title that is 48 characters long, but in the Facebook Developer section where we configure the App Display Name, which seems to need to match the facebook page name, there is a 32 character limit.

Does anyone know how can we achieve the above goal, keeping in mind that changing the name of the Organization's Page it not an option?

Alternatively, is there any way to alter where that "Shared via *_*" link directs users to?

Comment: I would suggest filing a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs that you can't connect a page because the name is over 32 characters

Comment: Done, although I'm not convinced this is necessarily a bug and not an issue with our setup.