# Facebook Login connects Page to App and Page shows subscribed but App does not

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, chatbot

### Problem:

I am unable to fully subscribe my Facebook App+Webhook to a Facebook Page using Facebook Login. The Page subscribes to the App, but the App+Webhook do not receive any messages from the Page.

---

### Steps I am Following:

**0. App is in developer mode with these permissions enabled:**

```
manage_pages - before review
read_page_mailboxes - before review
pages_messaging - approved review
```

(In Dev mode I test as admin of App and Page)

**1. User clicks the Login button and it asks for these permissions:**

```
email, manage_pages, pages_show_list, pages_messaging, pages_messaging_phone_number, pages_messaging_subscriptions, public_profile
```

**2. User clicks Accept to grant all those permissions.**

And this is returned when sending GET request to `/me/permissions` using the `user_access_token`

```
0: {permission: "email", status: "granted"}  
1: {permission: "manage_pages", status: "granted"}   
2: {permission: "pages_show_list", status: "granted"}  
3: {permission: "pages_messaging", status: "granted"}  
4: {permission: "pages_messaging_phone_number", status: "granted"}  
5: {permission: "pages_messaging_subscriptions", status: "granted"}  
6: {permission: "public_profile", status: "granted"}
```

**3. Send GET request to `/me/account` to get an array of data about the user's Page(s).**

The user's Facebook Pages, are each returned with a `page_id` and a `page_access_token`.

```
data: {  
    0: {
        access_token: "PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
        category: "Business Service"
        category_list: {
            0: {id: "xxxxxx", name: "Business Service"}
        }
        id: "PAGE_ID"
        name: "PAGE_NAME"
        tasks: ["ANALYZE", "ADVERTISE", "MODERATE", "CREATE_CONTENT", "MANAGE"]
    }
}
```

**4. Display the PAGE_NAMEs for the user to select which one to subscribe to my Facebook App.**

User clicks on appropriate Page to trigger Step 5.

**5. Send POST request to `/PAGE_ID/subscribed_apps`**

I use the correct PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN for the page the user clicks.
And I include these `subscribed_fields`

```
var subscribeAppFields = [
    "messages",
    "messaging_optins",
    "messaging_postbacks",
    "messaging_handovers",
    "standby"
]; 

...

FB.api( "/"+pageID+"/subscribed_apps",
   "POST",
    {
        subscribed_fields : subscribeAppFields,
        access_token : pageAccessToken
    },
    function (response) { ... } 
);
```

Sending GET request to `/PAGE_ID/subscribed_apps` returns:

```
{success: true}
```

---

### Result

If I check that Facebook Page's settings, my App is shown under "Connected Apps":

[image]

And I even set the page "Primary Receiver for Handover Protocol" to be the App.

[image]

But messages sent to the Facebook Page, is not being received by the App's Webhook. And when I check my app settings, it does not show my Page under "Subscribed Pages".

[image]

I expect that the Page's messages would go to my App and Webhook, and I expect the Page name to appear in the above picture under "Subscribed Pages".

I can manually subscribe the Page to the Webhook using the App Messenger Settings dropdown, and the webhook will receive messages succesfully. But the whole point of using Facebook Login here is to avoid doing that manually, which also requires me to be an admin of any Page that wants to connect.

The purpose is for other Page owners to grant permission and automatically connect their Page to my App / Webhook / Chatbot.

---

### Question

How do I complete the Page - App subscription so that Page messages are passed to the App's Webhook?

---

I have read and followed or tried these:

Related Questions

> [cannot-subscribe-page-to-facebook-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163590/cannot-subscribe-page-to-facebook-app)
>   [subscribe-facebook-page-to-external-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877621/subscribe-facebook-page-to-external-app)
>   [subscribed-apps-page-and-app-access-token-generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216018/facebook-messenger-subscribed-apps-page-and-app-access-token-generation)
>   [cant-connect-facebook-app-to-facebook-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170970/cant-connect-facebook-app-to-facebook-page)
>   [subscribe-facebook-test-pages-to-facebook-apps-webhook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51996845/how-to-subscribe-facebook-test-pages-to-facebook-apps-webhook)
>   [chatbot-generate-page-tokens-for-the-pages-you-dont-own-using-facebook-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319028/chatbot-generate-page-tokens-for-the-pages-you-dont-own-using-facebook-login)

Documentation

> [Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login)
>   [Login Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/overview/)
>   [Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)
>   [Subscribed Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/#Creating)

Comment: Assuming that you did not get this reviewed by Facebook yet, you need to test this with user accounts that have a role in your app - that the case? (Needs to be for both the page admin, and the user that is messaging the page, I would assume.) Did you complete all the other steps before successfully, including sending of a test webhook request to your app?

Comment: Yes, I am the admin of both the app and the page and I am the user sending the message just for testing before the review. The app is actually connected and working with another page that I manually subscribed (erased from pic). So I can confirm that the webhook and chatbot work successfully once the App Webhook is fully subscribed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution Part 1:** If your page shows subscribed but your App does not, then that means you have the USER `manage_pages` permission but not the APP `manage_pages` permission enabled.

All the steps from the question are correct. But it continued to fail for me.

**Solution Part 2:** It continued to fail for me because the accounts I used to test with had lingering permissions already set from earlier attempts, and even though I had updated the app and/or the Login with new user/app permissions, the old permissions must have remained when making new attempts.

So I had to create an entirely new user and test page to properly test the updated App and Login process. But that was only to reveal the actual problem. An easier solution for testing Login is this:

You have to completely remove the user permissions you granted to your App after each Login (permission granting) attempt.
To reset your USER permissions for the App go to:  [facebook.com/settings?tab=business_tools](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=business_tools)